# Difference Between Objective C Class and UIViewController Subclass

Tags: objective-c, class, uiviewcontroller

I get two options under ios template "Objective C Class" and "UiViewController Subclass".
Can anybody explain to me what is the difference between "Objective C Class" and "UiViewController Subclass"? What do you use them? Basically in what case should I use "Objective C Class" and in what case should I use "UiViewController Subclass"?

Comment: Have you tried to create one of each and seen the difference? As far as Xcode goes it's just helping you pick a template for a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a viewController then you should create a subclass of UIViewController.
If you want to create a class with any general functionality, then you should create a subclass of Objective-C class.

Answer (score 3):

You should use UIViewController subclass if you want to create a subclass of UIViewController and Objective-C class if you want to create a generic class not subclassed from UIViewController.